# Select specific column from cursor record variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Using PostgreSQL, column values from a table for 1st record are stored in a record variable. for example: let the variable be:

```
recordvar
```

and different columns be:

```
name,id,gender,age
recordvar.name
```

But I want to retrieve that colum value like

```
var =name
```

then

```
recordvar.var
```

How can I do this? I don't want to use hstore.

Here is the sample code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_all_rooms()
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 

 total integer;
 titles TEXT DEFAULT '';
 rec_croom   RECORD;
 rec_delement integer;
 rec_locations   integer;
 rec_dname   varchar;
 starts_with text = NULL;
 ends_with text = NULL;
 de_name   varchar;
 --de_array   integer[];
 de_arr_val integer;
 sql text;
 cur_croom CURSOR
 FOR SELECT *
FROM  public.tmp_all_controlroom_2;

BEGIN

 -- Open the cursor
   OPEN cur_croom;

   LOOP
    -- fetch row into the film
      FETCH cur_croom INTO rec_croom;
    -- exit when no more row to fetch
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;


       SELECT locationid INTO rec_locations FROM location WHERE locationcode = rec_croom.location_code;



     FOR de_arr_val in select deid from dsmtbl WHERE dsid=74
      LOOP


    select name INTO de_name from tab1 where deid=de_arr_val;

        INSERT INTO datavalue (a,  b, c, d, e, value)
    VALUES(de_arr_val, 1, rec_croom.cday , rec_locations, 3154, rec_room.de_name);
    END LOOP;     

   END LOOP;

   -- Close the cursor
   CLOSE cur_croom;

   RETURN titles;
END; $BODY$
```

rec_room.de_name is not working

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: postgresql.........doing this in procedure function

Comment: Maybe you can use FETCH _cursorname INTO _recordvar; Then you can use _recordvar.name for example.

Comment: Hope Sample code will help in understanding problem

Comment: How many columns do you have in one record?

Comment: Almost 30 to 40 columns....... In Loop "de_name" Changes everytime which is the one of column in "rec_room"..............I just want to pass that name to "rec_room" to get the value of desired column..................it is not accessed with dot operator

Comment: The question and the code are not very clear. You do several select queries on several tables but don't say nothing about this tables. Try adding the tables structure and some test data.

Comment: I read your question twice and failed to understand what you are asking. I am pretty sure there is a solution if you ask properly.

Comment: Thanks for help from everyone.........Yes I know I didn't ask properly....I would have try if I didn't got the solution.....[ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html ] does it for me